# Passing information to another GSP

Tags: grails, parameter-passing, gsp

I have been trying to figure out how to pass values from a previous gsp page `list.gsp` to  my other gsp page `confirm.gsp`. I'm trying to pass all the values from `list.gsp` to `confirm.gsp` with the same exact styling from `list.gsp` just everything as a text based instead of the drop downs and also with other information I will pass later. This is my code  passing the values to `confirm.gsp`:

```
    forward(action: actionName, params: params)
```

I am using `forward` to pass those values to another specific handling function inside my controller and also sending it to `confirm.gsp` through the parameter `actionName` based upon certain events. Right now when it when I pass the values in it only brings up a blank white page, but I know the values are being passed because I am seeing them in my handling function for that page. Is there a better way of doing this or am I missing something to make this work?

Edit: Here is the controller action that forwards those parameters to my other function in the controller:

```
    if(testDBCheckArray != null){
        actionName = "confirm"
    }
```

And here is the other function that will handle the data:

```
  def confirm = {
    def term_id = params.term_id
    println("This works: " + params)
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the controller action(s) that handle the initial request and then forward that request on to your confirm.gsp.

Comment: There you go, that's what I have that handles it and sends the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a `forward` from controller, you could use `render(view:"confirm")` at the same line. Your data in `params` map will be available in the confirm.gsp page.

Comment: That still only displays a blank page. I currently have no styling or any code on my `confirm.gsp` so it shouldn't be interfering with anything.

Comment: You should write some code in your confirm.gsp page. If you want to reuse a part of your gsp code from list.gsp in confirm.gsp, make it a template and use <g:render /> tag to render.

Comment: You can also pass a flag as the parameter to the <g:render /> tag to switch between "dropdown" and "textfield".

Answer (score 0):

How about using [redirect](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html):

```
redirect(action: "actionName", params: params)
```

Or using [chain](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/chain.html):

```
chain(action: "actionName", model: [book: shawshankRedemption])
```

This one would be useful if you are sending more complex data, command objects, etc.